# Metrics from Operator Norms

Tags: metric-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $(\cdot,\cdot)_X$ be the inner product on $X$. It is well known that $|x|_X = \sqrt{(x,x)_X}$ is a norm on $X$ and $|x-y|_X$ is a metric on $X$. The norm on $X$ induces norms on $B(X)$, e.g. $||T|| = \sup_{x\in X}\{|Tx|_X:|x|_X=1\}$. Under what induced norms is $||T-V||$ a metric on $B(X)$?

Comment: If $||\cdot||$ is a norm on a vector space then $||x-y||$ defines a metric; this is immediate from the definitions. Just curious: what other norms on $B(X)$ did you have in mind, induced by the norm on $X$?

Comment: The main induced norm I'm interested in is the operator norm given, but there's other "operator topologies" given on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_topologies. In particular I've seen the idea of a sequence of operators "strongly" converging, presumably that $T_kx\rightarrow Tx$ for all $x\in X$. Looking at it again, I now realize that not all of these topologies, beside the norm topology, rely on having a norm in the first place.